# testing payu integration in php asking otp when test cards used

Tags: php, html, payu

i am trying to integrate payu in my website, so i have used the following code for integration:

```
<?php
// Merchant key here as provided by Payu
$MERCHANT_KEY = "pvKnwsxh";
// Merchant Salt as provided by Payu
$SALT = "xHfAKkAxzE";
// Change to https://secure.payu.in for LIVE mode
$PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in";
$action = '';
$posted = array();
if(!empty($_POST)) {
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
$posted[$key] = $value;
}
}
$formError = 0;
if(empty($posted['txnid'])) {
// Generate random transaction id
$txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
} else {
$txnid = $posted['txnid'];
}
$hash = '';
// Hash Sequence
$hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";
if(empty($posted['hash']) && sizeof($posted) > 0) {
if(
empty($posted['key'])
|| empty($posted['txnid'])
|| empty($posted['amount'])
|| empty($posted['firstname'])
|| empty($posted['email'])
|| empty($posted['phone'])
|| empty($posted['productinfo'])
|| empty($posted['surl'])
|| empty($posted['furl'])
|| empty($posted['service_provider'])
) {
$formError = 1;
} else {
//$posted['productinfo'] = json_encode(json_decode('[{"name":"tutionfee","description":"","value":"500","isRequired":"false"},{"name":"developmentfee","description":"monthly tution fee","value":"1500","isRequired":"false"}]'));
$hashVarsSeq = explode('|', $hashSequence);
$hash_string = '';
foreach($hashVarsSeq as $hash_var) {
$hash_string .= isset($posted[$hash_var]) ? $posted[$hash_var] : '';
$hash_string .= '|';
}
$hash_string .= $SALT;
$hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hash_string));
$action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
}
} elseif(!empty($posted['hash'])) {
$hash = $posted['hash'];
$action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var hash = '<?php echo $hash ?>';
function submitForm() {
if(hash == '') {
return;
}
var payuForm = document.forms.payuForm;
payuForm.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="submitForm()">
<h2>PayU Form</h2>
<br/>
<?php if($formError) { ?>
<span style="color:red">Please fill all mandatory fields.</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<?php } ?>
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" name="payuForm">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $MERCHANT_KEY ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid ?>" />
<table>
<tr>
<td><b>Mandatory Parameters</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Amount: </td>
<td><input name="amount" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['amount'])) ? '' : $posted['amount'] ?>" /></td>
<td>First Name: </td>
<td><input name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['firstname'])) ? '' : $posted['firstname']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email: </td>
<td><input name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['email'])) ? '' : $posted['email']; ?>" /></td>
<td>Phone: </td>
<td><input name="phone" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['phone'])) ? '' : $posted['phone']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product Info: </td>
<td colspan="3"><textarea name="productinfo"><?php echo (empty($posted['productinfo'])) ? '' : $posted['productinfo'] ?></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Success URI: </td>
<td colspan="3"><input name="surl" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['surl'])) ? '' : $posted['surl'] ?>" size="64" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Failure URI: </td>
<td colspan="3"><input name="furl" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['furl'])) ? '' : $posted['furl'] ?>" size="64" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa" size="64" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php if(!$hash) { ?>
<td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and after submitting its taking me to payu website for adding card details, i have used the following test card details:

> Card Type: Visa
>   Card: 4012 0010 3714 1112
>   CVV: 123
>   Name: Test
>   Expiry: 05/20

but this is asking me otp like the image below:

[image]

I have searched a lot and never saw anything like otp needed for test credentials, can anyone tell me where to get otp or how to avoid this otp thing.

Comment: Why do you believe it to be wrong? What were you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: @ADyson its test credentials for testing payu payment gateway, i have searched alot and no where it mentions you have to use otp for test credentials

Comment: Ok. You should add that detail to your question, not just in the comments. Press the "edit" button to add more info.

Comment: @ADyson okey...

Comment: use any of 6 digit code for test account for ex: 123456